# Processing external references in the Excel files with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've got a bunch of Excel files with references to another files on the server using formulas like this:

```
'http://192.168.1.2/[blank.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

Ips in formulas are hardcoded. I want to change them to reference another host and path, for example:

```
'http://192.168.1.3/reports/[report.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

Trying to use Apache POI for that like this:

```
for (int s = 0; s < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); s++) {
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(s);
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                cell.setCellFormula("'http://192.168.1.3/reports/[report.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to get the value (with `cell.getCellFormula()`)I got:

```
#REF!$A$1
```

The same I got when I open the file with MS Excel.

How to get this work properly?

P.S. Using Apache POI 3.8.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `cell.setCellFormula("='http://192.168.1.3/reports/[report.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1")`?

Comment: Can you try with Apache POI 3.11 beta 2? 3.8 is rather old, and there have been tonnes of formula fixes (including 3d refs like these) since then

Comment: @jbarker2160, no. Exception is thrown: `The specified formula '='http://192.168.1.3/reports/[report.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1' starts with an equals sign which is not allowed.`

Comment: @Gagravarr, tried that – same problem. Found an open bug related to this problem: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46670

Comment: Looks very similar to [this bug though](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55906), which is fixed though!